# generate route url for every item

Tags: meteor

I need ot be able to generate a url for the Item i'm viewing and send this url via email to allow the recipient to view the item through this url .
what's a good way to generate Meteor routes for every item created ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Iron-Router package](https://atmospherejs.com/iron/router), with [route parameters](https://github.com/iron-meteor/iron-router/blob/devel/Guide.md#route-parameters). For example:

```
Router.route('/items/:itemName', function() {
  var item = ItemsCollection.findOne({name : this.params.itemName});

  this.render('itemDisplay', {
    data : { itemToDisplay: item }
  });
});
```